# Why didn't including a 1099-INT figure change the bottom line in my tax return?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, interest, income

I prepared a tax return with Turbo and saved as pdf.  Later, I discovered a 1099-INT I had neglected to include, so I edited the return to include it.  But it did not change the amount of the refund.  (I thought it would reduce the amount of the refund slightly.)  Why is that?  Maybe because the amount was so small (a bit less than $30) that it didn't bump us up to the next box in the tax table?

In the old days, before I started using Turbo and still used pencil and paper, I could see what was going on better.

Answer (score 2):

What's your total taxable income? Generally, tax tables are in $50 steps, so yes - it could be that you didn't go across the boundary for the next value. See [i1040TT](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040tt.pdf). You'd be using the tax tables for income below $100K.

Comment: I'm going to delete the question.  I was comparing two PDFs -- turns out they were the same file.  Thanks though, after reading your question, I realized the taxable income was the same, and from there I discovered I was looking at the same thing, twice.